# how to highlight variables of c/c++ files in vim

Tags: variables, vim, highlight, keyword

I want to highlight variables in a C/C++ file .
such as:

```
    int num;// Highlighted  num
    char str;// Highlighted str

    struct data
    {
     int year;
     int month;
     };
     struct data *p,time;// Highlighted  p  time
     ..........
```

**How to highlight variables as given above** （num ,str, p,time.....）

I know we can  modify  syntax\c.vim to reach that，but how to write the syntax?

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you need to do two things:

1. Generate tags using `ctags`;
2. Generate syntax file using resulting tags file.

Now some details.

There are plugins to help you. Firstly, plugin [Indexer](http://goo.gl/ze6Pv) automatically generates tags for a whole project and keeps tags up-to-date. (i'm author of this plugin, so, if you have any problems using it, feel free to ask me)

And secondly, there's plugin [TagHighlight](http://goo.gl/WIIxg) to extra highlights variables, enums, typedefs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how to turn on syntax highligting, then you need to:

:syntax on

If it does not work, determine filetype first:

:set filetype?

Should print "cpp". If not, set it first:

:set filetype=cpp

Comment: but it doesn't highlight the variables (not the type of variable).