# TagHighlight and Indexer plugins integration

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635659/how-to-highlight-variables-of-c-c-files-in-vim), explaining that it would be easy/possible to interface vim's plugin [TagHighlight](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2646) and the plugin [Indexer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3221). I am struggling with TagHighlight configuration as  it refuses to use the tags generated through Indexer and still create its own files. Is there someone here who have succeed in configuring those two plugins together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I have finally gave up and get through the documentation to set it up manually.

In order to make the plugin work properly I have to add a file name taghl_config.txt below at the root of the project I have set up with Indexer.

taghl_config.txt:

> IncludeLocals:1
>
> DoNotGenerateTags:1
>
> TagFileDirModePriority:Explicit
>
> TagFileDirectory:/home/username/.indexer_files_tags
>
> TagFileName:C__SandBox
>
> TypesFileDirModePriority:Explicit
>
> TypesFileDirectory:/home/username/.indexer_files_tags/.C__SandBox_taghl

where C__SandBox is the tag file generated by Indexer and username your account name. The TypesFile's option are just directives to separate TagHighlight's files from my source files hence the directory must be created manually.